# Matrix form of a double sum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, brownian-motion

I am working on the multivariate case of the Fokker-Plank equation, and I would like to know if it is possible to write the following double summation as product of vectors and matrices only.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\sigma_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$$

Comment: I don't suppose you'd like the answer that its "just" a double contraction of the two matrices $\sigma : \operatorname{Hess}f$.

Answer (score 0):

If you write the matrix $A$ such that $$A_{i,j}=\sigma_{i,j} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$$

and $e$ the all-one matrix.

then $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n\sigma_{i,j} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}=e^TAe$$

Edit:

[Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) might be of interest to you.

Let $S_{i,j}=\sigma_{i,j}$ and $F_{i,j}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$, then the quantity of interest is $\operatorname{Trace}(\bar{S}^TF)=\operatorname{vec}(S)^T\operatorname{vec}(S)$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. Is there a way to do the same thing disentangling the partial derivatives from the $\sigma_{i,j}$s?

Answer (score 0):

Define the matrix $\sigma$ with components $\sigma_{ij}$ and the matrix $D^2f$ with components $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$, then your double sum can also be written as a trace:
$$ Tr( \sigma \cdot D^2f) $$